# VSCode - TSLint Error ENOTDIR invalid cwd

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I'm using VSCode with TSLint (v5.11.0).

I set up the VSCode to:
`"tslint.autoFixOnSave": true`
However, whenever I open any ts files I get this TS error on the output:

```
[Info  - 14:52:31] vscode-tslint: Status is OK
[Info  - 14:52:31] vscode-tslint: Cannot read tslint configuration - 'ENOTDIR invalid cwd /Users/batman/project/Command.ts'
```

Because of this error vscode does not automatically fix the TS issues in my tslint.json file.

It is not just this one file it is any typescript files I open. Please let me know how to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have a `tsconfig.json` file.

If you DO have one, it's not on the root folder of your project (aka cwd).

Please, refer to the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: I do have a valid `tsconfig.json` and `tslint.json` file at the root of my directory, yet I still get the error... it seems to me that `vscode-tslint` assume the incorrect cwd `vscode-tslint: Cannot read tslint configuration - 'ENOTDIR invalid cwd /Users/mbirsan/workspace/WSNAME/src/ProjectName/src/pages/home/home.tsx'`